# What are the details of Saudi Arabia's supposed plans to stop funding foreign mosques?

Tags: saudi-arabia, islam

In January, *Middle East Monitor* [reported](https://www.middleeastmonitor.com/20200125-s/) that Saudi Arabia was to stop funding mosques in foreign countries. They point to an unspecified article on the *Arabi21.com* website, which I believe refers to [this piece](https://arabi21.com/story/1239679/) (in Arabic). My rudimentary translation of part of the article is below:

> "We will stop financing the places of worship in foreign countries,"
>   [Saudi Minister of Justice, Muhammad bin Abdul Karim Al-Issa] was quoted by Swiss newspaper *Le Matin Dimanche* as saying.

So the initial source of this appears to be [this article](https://www.lematin.ch/suisse/story/28090213) by *Le Matin Dimanche* (in French). My translation of the relevant part below:

> This decision does not only concern Geneva, the same arrangements will
>   be made worldwide in collaboration with the national authorities.
>   "Particularly for security reasons. We must ensure that the mosques
>   are placed in safe hands, of course. Then we won't intervene any more"
>   he adds.

It seems clear that the decision to no longer fund this specific Genevan mosque has been made, but I'm unsure if there is an official Saudi government source that confirms this change in policy for the country. Does such a declaration of the policy change exist, or can the policy be otherwise implicitly confirmed/debunked by further recent instances of Saudi funding/de-funding of international mosques?